# How do I limit concurrent sftp / port forwarding logins

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I have ssh set up so my users can only access sftp and port forwarding, how can I limit the number of concurrent logins on a per user basis?

In my `sshd_config` file, I have `UsePAM` set to yes, and in `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, I have:

```
username             -       maxlogins       1
```

I also tried:

```
username             hard    maxlogins       1
```

Neither of these works and the users can still log in multiple times.

Comment: Are you testing it with root (uid 0) "username" by any chance? maxlogins maximum number of logins for this user except for this with uid=0

Comment: No I'm testing with ordinary user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, the maxlogins directly only applies to shell logins, i.e. ones handled by sshd. (Secure SHell).  Since you are interested in SFTP / portforwarding, you'll have to use something else.

You can modify the script given at this related question to detect sftpserver processes, or scponly.  It should also work for detecting excessive port forwarding.  Unfortunately it's not as clean as a simple directive.

Script: [How can I disconnect ssh users, or limit the number of ssh logins?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227316/how-can-i-disconnect-ssh-users-or-limit-the-number-of-ssh-logins)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **pam_limits** in your PAM for this?

In **/etc/pam.d/sshd**:

```
 session    required     pam_limits.so
```

Comment: I just checked, yes that's in there.  The limit works if the user logs into a shell but not if they are using SFTP / Port Forwarding only.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the *MaxSessions* option in _/etc/ssh/sshd_config_.
`man sshd_config`

Comment: no no no no no no